# Как уменьшить расстояние между ссылками

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Как уменьшить расстояние между ссылками, у которых задано расстояние при помощи flexbox

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}

.header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
}

.menu{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 67px;
    width: 90%;
}

.punkt-menu{
    width: 70%;
}

.punkt-menu ul{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    list-style: none;
}

.menu-link{
    color: #676767;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12pt;
}

.logo h1{
    color: #8d8d8d;
}

.logo h1 span{
    color: #1298dd;
}

a.menu-button {
  width: 150px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .6em 2em;
  outline: none;
  border-width: 2px 0;
  border-style: solid none;
  border-color: #46a4e6;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: linear-gradient(#37b2f8, #2289e9) #2289e9;
} 
/*end button*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Indo Tourism</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="menu">
            <div class="logo">
                <h1><span>Indo</span> Tourism</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="punkt-menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="menu-link">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="menu-link">About us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="menu-link">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="menu-button menu-link">Contact us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно указать justify-content: flex-start; и затем margin-right, сколько уже нужно.

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}

.header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
}

.menu{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 67px;
    width: 90%;
}

.punkt-menu{
    width: 70%;
}

.punkt-menu ul{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    list-style: none;
}

.menu-link{
    color: #676767;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12pt;
    
}

.logo h1{
    color: #8d8d8d;
}

.logo h1 span{
    color: #1298dd;
}

a.menu-button {
  width: 150px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .6em 2em;
  outline: none;
  border-width: 2px 0;
  border-style: solid none;
  border-color: #46a4e6;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: linear-gradient(#37b2f8, #2289e9) #2289e9;
} 
/*end button*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Indo Tourism</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="menu">
            <div class="logo">
                <h1><span>Indo</span> Tourism</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="punkt-menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="menu-link">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="menu-link">About us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="menu-link">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="menu-button menu-link">Contact us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: как то это немного не помогло

Comment: куда задавать маргины?

Comment: Что именно? Расстояния вообще нет между ссылками. Его теперь можно регулировать, используя margin-right. Margin задаётся для .menu-link

Comment: я задал justify-content: flex-start; классу .punkt-menu ul но когда задал margin-right: 40px; не чего не произошло

Comment: justify-content: flex-start задаётся для родительского элемента, т.е. для .punkt-menu ul, а margin-right уже непосредственно для ссылок, т.е. для .menu-link

Comment: Оу помогло, но а как вернуть в правый угол само меню

Comment: Не очень понял.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67673/discussion-between-brafik-and-alex).